# place several figure into one -tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees

I draw several trees and now I want to place them in a figure ( side by side or one below the other )

```
 \documentclass{report}

 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes}

 \begin{document}
 %First picture
 \begin{tikzpicture}[every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},] 
 \tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=40mm] 
 \tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=20mm] 
 \tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling distance=10mm] 
 \node (S) {S} 
  child{node (n) {N} child{node (mary) {mary}} }
  child{node (VP) {VP}     
        child{node{V} child{node(des){brought }}}
        child{node (np) {NP}   child{node{D} child{node (a) {a}}} child{node{N} child{node (cat) {cat}}}  }
        child{node{PP}  child{node{IN} child{node{to}}}     child{node{N}  child{node{school}}} } }
   ; 


  \end{tikzpicture}
   %Second picture
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},] 
  \tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=40mm] 
  \tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=20mm] 
  \tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling distance=10mm] 
  \node (VP) {VP}     
        child{node{V} child{node(des){brought }}}
        child{node (np) {NP}   child{node{D} child{node (a) {a}}} child{node{N} child{node (cat) {cat}}}  }
        child{node{PP}  child{node{IN} child{node{to}}}     child{node{N}  child{node{school}}} } ;


  \end{tikzpicture}
  %Third picture
 \begin{tikzpicture}[every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},] 

 \node(V){V}
     child{node(des){brought }};

\end{tikzpicture}


  %fourth picture
 \begin{tikzpicture}[every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt},] 

  \node (np){NP}
         child{node{D} child{node{a}} }
        child{node{N} child{node{a}} };


 \end{tikzpicture}

 % ..... the other picture
 \end{document}
```

So i want to make something like this :

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're drawing linguistic trees, you really should use the [`tikz-qtree`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-qtree) package.  Not only is the input syntax much easier, it also spaces nodes automatically for you.  As for positioning, you can use `\scope`s for the bigger pieces, or even simple `\hspace`s to arrange the pieces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.S 
        [.NP [.N Mary ]]
        [.VP [.V brought ] 
             [.NP [.D a ] [.N cat ]]
        ]
      ]
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\Tree [.VP [.V brought ] 
             [.NP [.D a ] [.N cat ]]
        ]
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=9cm]
\Tree [.NP [.D a ] [.N cat ]]
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,yshift=-4cm]
\Tree [.N cat ]
\hspace{1.25cm}
\Tree [.D a ]
\hspace{1.25cm}
\Tree [.N Mary ]
\hspace{1.25cm}
\Tree [.V brought ] 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Good advice... But where is the big white arrow? ;-)

Comment: @PolGab to do that i added \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]

\draw[<-,very thick,red]  (-0.9,-2) -- (-1.4,-2);

\end{scope}

Answer (score 3):

Howdy you could use relative positioning which basically allows you to say i want node X y away form Y:

```
 \documentclass{report}

 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes, positioning}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt}, every node/.append style={font=\tiny}] 
 \tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=20mm] 
 \tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=14mm] 
 \tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling distance=10mm] 
 \node  (S) at (0,0) {S} 
  child{node (n) {N} child{node (mary) {mary}} }
  child{node (VP) {VP}     
        child{node{V} child{node(des){brought }}}
        child{node (np) {NP}   child{node{D} child{node (a) {a}}} child{node{N} child{node (cat) {cat}}}  }
        child{node{PP}  child{node{IN} child{node{to}}}     child{node{N}  child{node{school}}} } }
   ; 

  \node (VP)  [right= 5cm of S]{VP}     
        child{node{V} child{node(des){brought }}}
        child{node (np) {NP}   child{node{D} child{node (a) {a}}} child{node{N} child{node (cat) {cat}}}  }
        child{node{PP}  child{node{IN} child{node{to}}}     child{node{N}  child{node{school}}} } ;


  \node (np) [right= 4cm of VP]{NP}
         child{node{D} child{node{a}} }
        child{node{N} child{node{a}} };

 \node(V) [below= 7cm of VP]{V}
     child{node(des){brought }};

 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

See also the  tikz/pgf guide for more information on relative positioning systems.  The above example will spread over page boundaries. You can play around with text size and sibling distances until your are satisfied.

**Update**
Altought i don´t like the idea to much i´d like to tell you that one could put all those trees into one single tree and tell tikz  not to draw the first level (or to draw it white as shown below).

```
 \documentclass{report}

 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes, positioning}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,red,inner sep=-2pt}, every node/.append style={font=\tiny}] 
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=37mm] 
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=25mm] 
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling distance=15mm] 
\tikzstyle{level 4}=[sibling distance=10mm] 

\node  (S) at (0,0) {}[edge from parent/.style={draw,white,thick},level distance=1mm]
child{node{a}
          child[edge from parent/.style={draw,red,thick},level distance=20mm]{node{D} child{node{a}} }
         child[edge from parent/.style={draw,red,thick},level distance=20mm]{node{N} child{node{a}} }}
child{node{PP}
        child[edge from parent/.style={draw,red,thick},level distance=20mm]{node (np) {NP}   child{node{D} child{node (a) {a}}} child{node{N} child{node (cat) {cat}}}  }
        child[edge from parent/.style={draw,red,thick},level distance=20mm]{node{PP}  child{node{IN} child{node{to}}}     child{node{N}  child{node{school}}} } }
        %  
child{node{S}
        child[edge from parent/.style={draw,red,thick},level distance=20mm]{node (n) {N} child{node (mary) {mary}} }
        child[edge from parent/.style={draw,red,thick},level distance=20mm]{node (VP) {VP}%
          child{node{V} child{node(des){brought }}}
          child{node (np) {NP}   child{node{D} child{node (a) {a}}} child{node{N} child{node (cat) {cat}}}  }
          child{node{PP}  child{node{IN} child{node{to}}}     child{node{N}  child{node{school}}} }} 
}


        ;

 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

The reason why i don´t like this one should be quite clear: we must explicitly tell tikz how we want  the subsequent levels to look like since in a tree options given in a higher level will be passed on until the end of the tree.